# what is the button called in android phone(go back to previous page)

Tags: android, webview

for android phone when we go back to previous activity.
we press some button at the bottom of the phone

what is the name of this button and override method?

I can not override or search because I do not know the name of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Your code
}
```

Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the method onBackPressed.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Put your code here
}
```